# Load Image Upon Textbox Selection

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have code below for DownloadFile() that loads an image to the screen from a directory.  I want to be able to have the image load as soon as the user clicks inside of a text box.  How can I achieve this in the idAssignmentNum() ?

```
protected void DownloadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filePath = (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument;
    imgRecon.ImageUrl = filePath;
}
protected void idAssignmentNum_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.textBox1.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.idAssignmentNum_Init);
```

Comment: I may be implementing this incorrectly but it does not seem to be working.  Are you saying that all I need to do is to put this within the idAssignmentNum_Init() and then place the DownloadFile() code from above below?

Comment: yes you can do this cn you be more specific why it is not working